# PHP loop to output image gallery in Bootstrap with four thumbnails per row

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, image-gallery

Ok so I've been trying to find a definitive answer to this question and have not found one - so please do not mark this as a duplicate because none of the answers on here have worked for me.

I have a simple set of images and the locations stored in a database table. I want to output them using PHP. I know all the MYSQL statements etc for doing this, however I can't seem to output one row with 4 thumbnails, close the row off then start all over again. I've tried using this so called count marker but to no avail. My code is very little I'm afraid but I'm pulling my hair out here.

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    echo '<div class="row">';
    for($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    $count++;
?>
```

I'm using the placeholder as an example. Has anybody actually solved this problem so it clear and precise? I do not see where to put the count variable in to the right place or is there an if statement that should be in there somewhere?

Please somebody help. As I said I'm literally at the end of my tether now.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Say for example I have 12 images and their respective thumbnails. I want the output to be 4 images per row so 3 rows if it's 12 images I have but at some point I'm going to end up with an odd number which shouldn't matter. I just want a simple out of the gallery thumbnail images using the bootstrap 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited answer:

```
<?php

$count_items = 12;

$columns = 4;

echo '<div class="row">';
for($i = 0; $i < $count_items; $i++) {
  if($i % $columns === 0 && $i > 0) {
    echo '</div><div class="row">';
  }
  echo '<div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Outputs:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't output Bootstrap rows with 4 thumbnail images per row until all images have been output. So say I've got exactly 12 image locations saved to the database table, I'd want the output to be 3 rows with 4 thumbnail images per row. Obviously the time will come when there are an odd number of images but the loop would need to run until all images have been output no matter how many there are.

Comment: Apologies...try my edited answer. I used your example placeholder image and believe it now does what you need. It's not super elegant but I believe it's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm very grateful. I didn't mean to sound rude or off as you can probably tell I've tried and tried and not managed to get it right so I do thank you so much for helping.